# Python: Lambda expression

Tags: python

I'm trying to take input as:

```
1.jpg 10.png 11.png 2.jpg 3.png
```

and print out to a list by using lambda expression:

```
['001.jpg', '010.png', '011.png', '002.jpg', '003.png']
```

---

```
files = input().split()

print(list(map('{0:03d}.{1}'.format(lambda x: int(x.split('.')[0]), x.split('.')[1], files))))
```

I thought I did it right. But it occurs an error as:
  *AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'*

What am I missing?

Comment: show the error.

Comment: @hpaulj AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: You can split a string into a list of strings.  Make sure you understand what each variable is.

Comment: I'm not able to get your error. My error indicates that passing a lambda function as an argument to format is not allowed. The answer given by @Ofer Sadan is very elegant, you should use it. Since you want to know what you missed I sugest to look at this way of doing it `print (list (map(lambda x : '{0:03d}.{1}'.format(int(x.split('.')[0]), x.split('.')[1]), files) ))`

Answer (score 3):

You don't need any map or lambda, just `zfill`:

```
print([x.zfill(8) for x in input().split()])
```

Adjust `8` in this example to whatever length you need

Comment: Didn't even think of `zfill` nice answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can use simple `str.split` and calculate the padding from the length of the digit as a string:

```
s = '1.jpg 10.png 11.png 2.jpg 3.png'
result = list(map(lambda x:'0'*(3-len(x.split('.')[0]))+x, s.split()))
```

Output:

```
['001.jpg', '010.png', '011.png', '002.jpg', '003.png']
```

Comment: Can you help me out on my code as well? I just want to know what I'm missing

Answer (score 1):

A list comprehension is more efficient here than `map` and `lambda` and way more readable.

```
s = '1.jpg 10.png 11.png 2.jpg 3.png'
result = ['{0:0>3}.{1}'.format(*x.split('.')) for x in s.split()]
```